# Xamarin Android toolbar how to add items dynamically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-toolbar

I have implemented android toolbar as per the instructions given in xamarin android guides [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/tool-bar/part-3-toolbar-compatibility/)

using example code:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {           
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.mainMenu, menu);

            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

and xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_share"
       local:showAsAction="ifRoom"
       android:title="Share" />
  <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
       local:showAsAction="ifRoom"
       android:title="Settings" />
</menu>
```

Now i want to add items to toolbar that will come from my web api , they are basically links to our pages such as privacy policy etc. but i cant find any example on menu.Add method that does this. basically what i need is to constrcut meny items from my json which returns:

```
[{
pageid:1,
pagename:"home",
pagehtmllink:"....."
},
{
pageid:2,
pagename:"About",
pagehtmllink:"....."
},
...........
]
```

how to achieve this from code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IMenu` has an `Add` method that you can call:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.main_menu, menu);

        menu.Add(0, 99, 0, "DB Copy to SDCard (Debug)");

        return base. OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

For the parameters, review the Android docs: [Menu.html#add](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

To capture the menu selection, you can check the `IMenuItem.ItemId` value:

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
        case 99:
            DoSomething();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks to your suggestion i was able to add the menu items, how to bind the click event to them?

Comment: i have accepted your answer, please let me know if i need to ask a new question or you will be kind enough to amend in edits ;)

Comment: @Alok I updated my answer to include the menu selection.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need that you can create a tabbed page and on each page you create a webview

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Gray;

        var homePage = new HomePage();
        var accountPage = new AccountPage();
        var ordersPage = new OrdersPage();
        var promotionsPage = new PromotionsPage();
        var searchPage = new SearchPage();

        homePage.Icon = "imgs_main.png";
        accountPage.Icon = "imgs_account.png";
        ordersPage.Icon = "imgs_orders.png";
        promotionsPage.Icon = "imgs_promotions.png";
        searchPage.Icon = "imgs_search.png";

        homePage.Title = "Home";
        accountPage.Title = "Account";
        ordersPage.Title = "Orders";
        promotionsPage.Title = "Promotions";
        searchPage.Title = "Search";

        Children.Add(homePage);
        Children.Add(accountPage);
        Children.Add(ordersPage);
        Children.Add(promotionsPage);
        Children.Add(searchPage);

    }
```

Comment: although your answer is good for any future requirements , i would still like to go with toolbar its a design necessity, also this is xamarin.android not forms

Comment: just a possibility, xamarin.forms is just as good as xamarin.android with the advantage if in a couple months you want to deploy on IOS the code is done.

Comment: i had very bad experiences with xamarin.forms it was like bugged on each step, so i am not going that way until xamarin comes up with various fixes for it. i am ok with android as most of my projects are not iOS anyways

Comment: also for a kickass ui, you dont need to do much on native platforms but with forms you have to add custom renders and the list goes on with each different variations

Comment: Yea that is annoying but when you get the custom renderers right it becomes just a normal daily task.

Comment: i would be nice to see a github repo encompassing various custom controls but its too much work on individual level